# edit node value in a xml files and update in a random number with powershell

Tags: shell, powershell

I wold like edit with powershell a node and update this with an random number

xml files node

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Configuration>
        <Other appsCode="V7{}appsCont-12-Win-GM">
            <Data key="appsnumbers">970767075516458272844213</Data>
        </Other>

</Configuration>
```

script

```
# load XML file into local variable and cast as XML type.
$doc = [xml](Get-Content ./test.xml)

$doc.root.one                                  

# find the value *970787075519458272844213* in the node and create a new one and update the xml files 


$doc.save("./testNew.xml")
```

ty for any help :)

Comment: can you post a valid XML file to test against?

Comment: thank you for posting the XML. after removing the invalid starting whitespace, the xml works nicely. [*grin*] you can access the value in question thus [presuming the xml has been loaded into `$InStuff`] >>> `$InStuff.Configuration.Other.Data.'#text'`

Answer (score 0):

<s>IIRC $doc.save() won't accept a relative path.</s>

According to [mklement0's good hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972848/edit-node-value-in-a-xml-files-and-update-in-a-random-number-with-powershell/54974224?noredirect=1#comment96708304_54974224) the remedy I chose is OK, while the reason didn't hit [the point](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428)

```
## Q:\Test\2019\03\03\SO_54972848.ps1
$FileIn = ".\test.xml"
$FileOut= Join-Path (Get-Item .) "testNew.xml"

$doc = [xml](Get-Content $FileIn)

$doc.Configuration.Other.Data.'#text'
$doc.Configuration.Other.Data.'#text' = -join (1..24|%{get-random -min 0 -max 9})
$doc.Configuration.Other.Data.'#text'

$doc.save($FileOut)
```

Comment: It does accept a relative path, it's just that it is relative to what _.NET_ thinks the current directory is, which is _not_ in sync with _PowerShell_'s current directory (location). Therefore, always use a full path when calling .NET methods. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428